# Building MinGW-w64 from Source code problem

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw-w64, msys2

I am trying to build MinGW-w64 on Windows, I have downloaded MinGW-w64 and GCC-12.2.0 source code and I used Msys2 as an environment, and followed these steps on this link: [How to build mingw-w64](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-doc/howto-build/mingw-w64-howto-build.txt)

and I built it statically successfully and I can creating programs with it,
my problem is when try to build it as static and shared, and when I built it, and trying to test it with a simple HelloWorld program I am getting this error:
c:/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s: No such file or directory
c:/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_s: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

and this is my configuration:
`../src/gcc/configure --prefix=/mingw32 --with-sysroot=/mingw32 --build=i686-w64-mingw32 --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-pkgversion='Built by Dahy Alla
m Ali' --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-threads=win32 --enable-plugins --enable-libatomic --enable-ful
ly-dynamic-string --enable-checking=release --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-lto --enable-bootstrap --disable-multilib --disable-win32-registry --disable-sjlj-exceptions -disabl
e-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-verbose --disable-rpath --disable-nls --disable-werror --with-arch=i686 --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-boot-ldflags=-static-libstdc++ --with-stage1-ldfl
ags=-static-libstdc++`

Please help me, and sorry for my English, and I am new to Stackoverflow.

I tried solve it, but I couldn't.

Comment: Building compiler toolchains from source is a very difficult process.  You often have to patch GCC so it will search for its files in the right place.  You can see the patches the MSYS2 developers are using [here](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-gcc).  Why are you trying to do this instead of just installing the appropriate MSYS2 toolchain package?  Try opening a mingw64 shell and running `pacman -S $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX-toolchain`.